# Rails API - ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments - when trying to assign params[:id] to instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is definitely an easy one, but its giving me a hard time, and it will probably good to learn about ruby concepts.

Im getting a `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)` on the `set_user` method, that simples fetchs an param from url and assigns it to a variable.

I am able to print to params just fine on console, when I am debuging, I also tried using the value itself by hand, and I still get the error.

What concept Am I Missing? I am using ruby 2.7.1 and rails 6

`"trace": "app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:27:in 'update'"`

```
module Api
  module V1
    require 'authenticate_user'
  
      class UsersController < ApplicationController
        include AuthenticateUser
  
        before_action :authenticate_user
        before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  
        def update
          if @user.update
            json_response(UsersSerializer.new([@user], includable_params).as_json)
          else
            error_response(@user.errors, 422)
          end
        end

        def destroy
          @user.destroy!

          head :no_content
        end

        private

        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password)
        end

        def set_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end
  
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't seems to be on your `set_user`, the cause is that you aren't passing any arguments to `update` method. Your update action should look like this:

```rb
def update
  if @user.update(user_params) # <-- here was the problem
    json_response(UsersSerializer.new([@user], includable_params).as_json)
  else
    error_response(@user.errors, 422)
  end
end
```

Comment: Geez.. Lost so much time. Thanks!
I was misleaded by the log, that was pointing to the ` set_user line